# Jenkins failed to execute goal maven release

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jenkins, github

I'm running a jenkins maven job and it fails with the following error when it was trying to perform release step.I've searched for a similar issue on stack over flow but I couldn't find one suitable to mine.

my pom.xml file is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.jenkins.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <!-- Package type is declared here -->
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>helloworld</name>
    <description>Hello World Spring Boot Application</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:username/repo.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:username/repo.git</developerConnection>
        <url>git@github.com:username/repo.git</url>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The Jenkins Log is here.....

```
<omitted for brevity>
[INFO] [prepare] 11/17 scm-commit-release
[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git add -- pom.xml"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.[*******]\workspace\devops01
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  26.146 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-10T11:20:32+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M1:prepare (default-cli) on project helloworld: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-add command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[ERROR] operable program or batch file.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M1:prepare (default-cli) on project helloworld: Unable to commit files
<omitted for brevity>
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.scm.ReleaseScmCommandException: Unable to commit files
Provider message:
The git-add command failed.
Command output:
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractScmCommitPhase.checkin (AbstractScmCommitPhase.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractScmCommitPhase.performCheckins (AbstractScmCommitPhase.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.ScmCommitPreparationPhase.runLogic (ScmCommitPreparationPhase.java:69)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractScmCommitPhase.execute (AbstractScmCommitPhase.java:78)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare (DefaultReleaseManager.java:204)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare (DefaultReleaseManager.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease (PrepareReleaseMojo.java:346)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute (PrepareReleaseMojo.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
Build step 'Conditional steps (multiple)' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

FYI, Jenkins installed on Windows 10. My Git Path configuration in Jenkins is

> [Git Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYlF5.png)

I really appreciate your help and I'm stuck on this for a day, not knowing what to do and I'm reaching you all fantastic people for help.

Comment: The issue is simply as stated in the output that on your Jenkins `'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,` meaning git is not installed. this means it needed to be configured via global tools configuration...

Comment: Hi khmarbaise,Thank you for your kind reply. I have configured the path as shown below. FYI, my Jenkins is on Windows 10. Git path set to "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between Git Path on Jenkins and the path for Windows.

The Jenkins Path you configured will be used by Jenkins Jobs when you configure a Git version control system.

However Maven and the release plugin did not see this path at all, they are executed on the Windows Host and have (almost) the same path and environment like a normal Windows shell.

So you need to add Git to the path on the Windows 10 Host. Or set the path manually in the shell when executing `mvn release:prepare release:perform`.

To see what Jenkins shell uses, create a freestyle job and execute a bat command:

```
SET
```

And check the console output there should be a Path variable which must include an folder with a Git executable.

Comment: Hi mszalbach, That's very kind of you. Thank you for a quicjk response. I have now figured it out that my path environment variable set for git on user profile didn't take effect and I had to set a system wide Environment variable and reboot and it looks like it's now looking at the git properly but now I'm getting another error about git push, where it says [ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] Host key verification failed.
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please make sure you have the correct access rights

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with jenkins looking and accessing github, What should I do on windows and on github in order for this to work. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi made a little progress, but I get a public key error. [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M1:prepare (default-cli) on project helloworld: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] user1@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: The git command must use the correct public key to authenticate against github. So the user running Jenkins need to have a key pair in its .ssh folder and you need to allow this in github. Or you add the correct key with ssh-add before executing mvn release. Or you use the SSH Agent Plugin for Jenkins.

Comment: Hi mazalbach, I have figured that one out, but thank you for your help. Now I'm getting yet another error when trying to deploy to tomcat server, ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy [C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.[*******]\workspace\devopsprod\helloworld-1.0.0.war], it looks like when it was copying the file from repo to work space with curl for somereason the file is not getting downloaded fully.

Comment: command used to copy is on windows is something like this.curl -O http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/jenkins/maven/helloworld/%tag:~1%/helloworld-%tag:~1%.war

Comment: This is now an other problem not related to git or Jenkins anymore, which should not be discussed in comments. Gather enough info like output from server log your deploy and curl commands and open an new stackoverflow question.

Comment: Thank you mazalbach for your help.